# Entity Framework EDMX Copy to Output Directory

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have my edmx `Metadata Artifact Processing` set to `Copy to Output Directory`. The csdl/msl/ssdl get copied fine to the bin directory of the project with the model, but none of the other projects which reference this project get the artifacts copied into the bin directories.

I have several end exes/services/etc that require these files and I don't want to add a post build task for all of them. Is there any way I can get these resources deployed correctly? Or can I just use the raw edmx file somehow (not the csdl/msl/ssdl)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shame I couldn't find a better answer...but I just ended up leaving them set as Metadata Artifact Processing and then in a static constructor for my ObjectContext type I extracted the csdl/msl/ssdl using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream() and wrote them to disk in the executing assembly's location.